# Updating parse for 64 bit compatiblity

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Hi I have an old module using the parse framework that needs to be updated with a newer edition of the framework V1.2.5+ in order to work with 64 bit. Parse had a lengthy blog post here: (http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/facebooks-latest-ios-sdk-update-and-what-it-means-for-you/) about how to do so but its missing from the website now and all my efforts to find it have failed. Does anyone still know the instructions on how to do this?
Thanks.

EDIT: Need to update parse for this module in particular: https://github.com/ewindso/ios-parse-titanium-module